# Compare two comma-separated columns in two different oracle tables

Tags: oracle, compare

I want to compare a comma-separated column in oracle table with another comma-separated column in a different table. If the all the values (within comma-separated column and irrespective of their order) on column one are contained within column two  it should not return that row.

For example  -

1. Column 1 has  a,b,c,def 
   Column 2 has  a,c,b

   This should not be returned as a,c and b in column 2 are contained
   within column 1 irrespective of their order.
2. Column 1 has a,cl,owd 
   Column 2 has a,owd,pp

   This row should be returned because column 2 has 'pp' which is not
   contained within Column 1.
3. Column 1 has vvv,ccc,rr
   Column 2 has ccc,rr

   This row should not be returned.

Can I accomplish this in SQL ? Not expecting a procedure or function.

Thanks for all the help !!

Comment: Those rules are quite confusing, the description in text vs the examples isn't matching.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in a single column in the first place. It would be better if you re-designed your datamodel (i.e. solving the root cause) instead of fighting the symptons of the wrong design.

Answer (score 2):

First: I think your example doesn't match your question.

But concentrating on your question: *If the all the values (within comma-separated column and irrespective of their order) on column one are contained within column two it should not return that row.*

You need to parse the csv into a set (the `regexp_substr` part) and then check if the set from column two fully contains the set from column one (the `minus` part):

```
SELECT *
  FROM csv
 WHERE EXISTS
         (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (col1, '[^,]+', 1, ROWNUM)
            FROM DUAL
           CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= LENGTH (col1) - LENGTH (REPLACE (col1, ',')) + 1
          MINUS
          SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (col2, '[^,]+', 1, ROWNUM)
            FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= LENGTH (col2) - LENGTH (REPLACE (col2, ',')) + 1
         )
;
```

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3cdb3/1 for working example.